# Issue converting Data frame datatype from object to float64

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to convert the datatype of y_test from object to float64. I first converted into an array of strings ( **In[54]** ) and then to an array of floating point numbers (**Inputs [83] & [85]**)  but it is not added to the y_test data frame.

y_test feature CO(ppm) is still displayed as *object* datatype ( **Out[90]** ).

**Can someone please help me understand how to accomplish this? Thank you.**

[image]

Comment: A few changes here would be helpful: 1) please post code as text rather than as an image; 2) for this question you could post a dataset of just a couple of entries which would illustrate your problem, and then we could run that ourselves which would help in understanding what's going on. It's definitely best to aim for a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) whenever possible.

Comment: Please provide us with example input and desired output

Comment: All those `Out` lines just show a new array generated by the action.  Nothing is being changed in-place.  `y_test` remains unchanged.

Comment: That makes sense. I will post better framed questions next time. Thank you for your comments everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
y_test['CO'] = y_test.CO.apply(lambda x: x.replace(',','')).astype(float)
```

Comment: Got it. String to float conversion also replaces the comma values. Thanks.